Excel SUMIF with Workbook links (to Sharepoint)
I am preparing an Excel file that reads and aggregates data from another Excel file stored on Sharepoint. This works with simple references, but when using a reference to the other file in a SUMIFS formula I run into problems.
When having both files open in the Desktop app it works fine. When I open only the file that does the aggregation and choose to update linked data, then the formulas with SUMIF show #VALUE. Once I open the other file in the Desktop app the SUMIF formulas start working.
Also on the Web app I see only #VALUE and cannot get the SUMIF formulas to work at all.
Here is an example of a SUMIF that shows this behavior.
=SUMIFS('https://our_domain.sharepoint.com/our_url/[our_filename.xlsx]our_sheet'!$R:$R,'https://our_domain.sharepoint.com/our_url/[our_filename.xlsx]our_sheet'!$G:$G,$B29)
A plain reference works fine, even if the other file is not open and in the Web app:
='https://our_domain.sharepoint.com/our_url/[our_filename.xlsx]our_sheet'!G3
Has anyone an idea of what I am doing wrong? Or is this just a limitation of SUMIF and similar aggregation functions in conjunction with Workbook links?

Maybe this site can help. Additional info or this

Thanks, that looks very promising, I‘ll test it tomorrow!

Unfortunately it did not work. The proposed solution for SUMIF with only one criteria does work, but if I try to use multiple criteria with AND to replace SUMIFS, it does not. I created a separate question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79136003/sum-with-if-and-and
